# Uninitialized Constant in Rake Tasks

Tags: rake, ruby-on-rails-3

Here's the setup:

New Rails app, then put this test_rake.rake in lib/tasks:

```
task :testclass do
  HelloClass.hello
end`
```

Put hello_class.rb in app/models, or in lib/ with this line: `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` added to config.rb

```
class HelloClass
  def self.hello
    puts 'hello_class'
  end
end
```

rake testclass gives this error:

```
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2503:in `const_missing'
/Users/name/Sites/Rails/indexapp/lib/tasks/test_class.rake:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `block in execute'
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `block in top_level'
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `block in run'
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas? I've uninstalled and reinstalled Ruby via RVM, deleted / rebuilt the gemset, printed out the autoload paths to make sure hello_class.rb was in one of them...

I can manually require HelloClass from within the .rake file, but then I have to do the same for anything HelloClass depends on - say, for example, if HelloClass includes HTTParty or the task sets up a delayed job.

Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Intend the code with 4 spaces to keep the formatting.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

If you start your rake task with `task :testclass => :environment do`, your Rails environment will be loaded and available for the task.

Comment: Oh man! And it was right there in one of my other apps, too. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

This also happens when you correctly specify the dependency `task :testclass => :environment do`, but have enabled `threadsafe!`.

To fix this if you enabled `threadsafe`, do this:

```
   # in your application.rb or environment file:
   #
   config.threadsafe! unless File.split($0).last == 'rake' # unless this is a rake task
```

Comment: +1 your solution doesn't work but your assessment is correct. My task worked if I disabled thread safe.. This is not good.... this is rails 3.2.17

Comment: Fixing your conditional, it needs to be `.split($0)[1]`

Comment: For me this showed up only on Production, it worked fine on dev